# Package.appxmanifest Capabilites addition entry is failing

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-10

I am using the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability addition in my UWP project. This project was developed in the early fall of last year and thoroughly debugged with numerous successful test cases. It hasn't been used since then. Now, when integrating it into a larger product, the same code fails. Version control shows no changes since that time.

The capability addition that is failing is:
`<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess"/>`

The `Package.appxmanifest` file shows an error indicating that this line is an invalid child element.

The program execution fails with an `UnauthorizedAccessException`

Here is the Package manifest that is failing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

  <Identity
    Name="2eff3ebf-1a30-4bcd-8f77-d10f54e5ec80"
    Publisher="CN=JAlden"
    Version="1.0.0.0" />

  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="2eff3ebf-1a30-4bcd-8f77-d10f54e5ec80" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>CodeGenerator</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>JAlden</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="CodeGenerator.App">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="CodeGenerator"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
        Description="CodeGenerator"
        BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png"/>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess"/>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Additionally, this application is being developed for a enterprise, not the app store, and will be side-loaded.

Comment: What's your project's Target and min version? OS build version? Please also check **'settings -> privacy -> file system'** to see if your app can access your file system.

Comment: I think this was added in 17134, so make sure MinVersion is 17134, Target is 17763 and in manifest change MinVersion to 10.0.17134.0" and MaxVersionTested to "10.0.17763.0" and look in settings app that it is allowed for apps to do file access: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC879683.png

Comment: Thanks @Xavier Xie and magicandre1981 the privacy setting for the app had been turned off. I forgot it even existed.

Comment: It seemed that you have reloved your issue. I made a reply on this thread. You could mark it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later. And also thanks for @magicandre1981's effort on this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [*magicandre1981*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1466046/magicandre1981) said, the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability is introduced from [build 17134](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-build-17134#develop-windows-apps), so you need to make sure that your project meets the requirement.

And then, you need to check **'settings -> privacy -> file system'** to see if your app can access your file system.

[image]

Actually, the document [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) also has mentioned this point.

> This is a restricted capability. Access is configurable in Settings > Privacy > File system. Because users can grant or deny the permission any time in Settings, you should ensure that your app is resilient to those changes. If you find that your app does not have access, you may choose to prompt the user to change the setting by providing a link to the [Windows 10 file system access and privacy](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-10-file-system-access-and-privacy) article. Note that the user must close the app, toggle the setting, and restart the app. If they toggle the setting while the app is running, the platform will suspend your app so that you can save the state, then forcibly terminate the app in order to apply the new setting. In the April 2018 update, the default for the permission is On. In the October 2018 update, the default is Off.